# Why does a program launched by echoing into sh persist after parent termination?

Tags: shell, process, posix, i3, process-management

I was looking at `dmenu_run`, which is the default `dmenu` script to launch a program, and saw this part of it that intrigued me:

`[..other stuff..] | dmenu | sh &`

So I did some testing.

## Prerequisites information

I am running GNU/Linux.
`sh` is `dash` on my system. My login shell is `bash`.
`st` and `xterm` are terminal emulators.
Replace `$XTERMPID` with the PID of the `xterm` window created during testing. You can use `xprop` to get it.
`xterm` does not seem to produce log output, unless there is a problem. You can replace it with another program that actually produces log output for doing that part of the testing.

## Testing

### Scenario #1 - running `xterm` (or `xterm &`) in `st`:

You can see the xterm logs in `st`.

`pstree -s $XTERMPID` output: `systemd───sddm───sddm-helper───i3───st───bash───xterm───bash`

#### After closing `st`

`xterm` gets killed.

### Scenario #2 - running `echo xterm | sh` (or `echo xterm | sh &`) in `st`:

You can see the `xterm` logs in `st`.

`pstree -s $XTERMPID` output: `systemd───sddm───sddm-helper───i3───st───bash───sh───xterm───bash`

#### After closing `st`:

`xterm` survives somehow (This is the part I don't understand. Shouldn't all children get killed?)

`pstree -s $XTERMPID` output: `systemd───xterm───bash`

### Scenario #3 - running `setsid -f xterm` in `st`:

You **can't** see the `xterm` logs in `st`.

`pstree -s $XTERMPID` output: `systemd───xterm───bash`

#### After closing `st`:

Unchanged as expected.

### Scenario #4 - running `echo "echo xterm | sh" | sh` (or `echo "echo xterm | sh &" | sh &`) in `st`:

You can **still** see the `xterm` logs in `st`, yet `xterm` is not a child of `st` anymore. I don't understand this either.

`pstree -s $XTERMPID` output: `systemd───sh───xterm───bash`

#### After closing `st`:

Unchanged as expected.

## Questions:

- When `st` is killed in scenario #2, why does `xterm` not get killed when its parent `sh` gets killed?
- Is it `st` or the kernel that kills the children?
- Does it only kill immediate children? Then why does a program running in a shell in a terminal die when you close the terminal?
- Why in scenario #4 does the output of `xterm` still show up in `st` even though `xterm` is not a child of `st`? How does this work?

## Testing #2

### running `(echo "echo xterm | sh &" | sh &) >/dev/null 2>&1` from an `i3blocks` script

Works until you restart i3 `i3-msg restart` or Super+Shift+R. The window will still be there, but the actual processes will be killed, and the window will be filled with black.
See this bug report for more detailed information: https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks/issues/483

### running `setsid -f xterm` from an `i3blocks` script

Works with no problems

## Questions:

- What extra thing does `setsid -f` do that double piping into `sh` doesn't? Why `setsid -f` work in the `i3blocks` scenario but not the other when they look the same with `pstree`?
- `setsid` seems to be a Linux only command, how to replicate it using POSIX compliant shell and coreutils only?
- Why is the window still visible if the processes died?

Comment: Related: [POSIX: sh - STDIN](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sh.html#tag_04_128_06); also: [OPTIONS section](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sh.html#tag_04_128_04) above STDIN.

Comment: Also related: [POSIX shell pipelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02), [POSIX shell asynchronous lists](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02).

Comment: About `exit`: [POSIX `_Exit` - Consequences of Process Termination](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html#tag_16_01_03_01). Quote: _Termination of a process does not directly terminate its children. The sending of a SIGHUP signal as described below indirectly terminates children in some circumstances._ Note: "some circumstances". It then continues: _If the process is a controlling process, the controlling terminal associated with the session shall be disassociated from the session, allowing it to be acquired by a new controlling process._ and so on.

Comment: Also: [exit(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html): _Except in the above cases, where the signalled processes may be
       children of the terminating process, termination of a process
       does not in general cause a signal to be sent to children of that
       process.  However, a process can use the prctl(2)_ [NB: Linux specific!] _PR_SET_PDEATHSIG operation to arrange that it receives a signal
       if its parent terminates._; see also [setsid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html).

Comment: Related question(s): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284325/how-to-make-child-process-die-after-parent-exits